# bind's queries per second by an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, bind

A table contains bind dns queries in a way like this:

```
10.30.2.218 | 86.214.218.178.in-addr.arpa|25.09.13 10:32:29,774000000
```

that is "client ip","query","query time"(as a timestamp)
I've been trying to come up with an SQL request that counts number of queries groupped for an ip address, but per second. And still fail.
I've tried this query:

```
select to_char(log_time, 'HH24:MI:SS'),log_client,count(*) from msint
group by log_time,log_client
order by 3 desc;
```

but it returns groupping by milliseconds and not seconds as I need.
I'd be very greatful if you give me a hint how  to get "per second requests".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the function results, not the field.  In other words,

```
group by to_char(log_time, 'HH24:MI:SS'), log_client
```